# Trying to prove Sard's lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is an exercise of *Analysis III* of Amann and Escher:

> [image]

*Note: here $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ is open.*

I was trying to follow the hint, however I cant finish a proof. My work so far:

Let $x_0\in C$. Now let $J_0$ the cube centered at $x_0$ with side length $r>0$ such that $J_0\subset X$. Then $\Phi(J_0)$ is compact and convex, and from the mean value theorem we find that
$$
\Phi(x)-\Phi(x_0)=\int_0^1\partial\Phi(x_0+t(x-x_0))(x-x_0)\, dt\tag1
$$
Hence
$$
|\Phi(x)-\Phi(x_0)|\le |x-x_0|\int_0^1\|\partial\Phi(x_0+t(x-x_0))\|\, dt\tag2
$$
Then setting $\rho(r):=\max_{x\in J_0}\int_0^1\|\partial\Phi(x_0+t(x-x_0))\|\, dt$ we find that
$$
\lambda_n(\Phi(J_0))\le \rho(r)^n\lambda_n(J_0)= (r\rho(r))^n\tag3
$$
Now note that $\|\partial \Phi(x_0)\|\le\max_{1\le k\le n}|\lambda_k|$, where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $\partial\Phi(x)_{\Bbb C}$ (where $\partial\Phi(x)_{\Bbb C}$ is the complexification of $\partial\Phi(x)$).

However Im stuck here. I cant see that $\lim_{r\to 0^+}\rho(r)=0$, what I see is that $\lim_{r\to 0^+}\rho(r)=\|\partial\Phi(x_0)\|$, what is not necessarily zero.

Some help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You need to use that $\|\partial \Phi(x_0) - \partial \Phi (x_0 + t (x-x_0))\|$ gets small as $t\to 0$, and then you need to estimate the measure of $\partial \Phi (x_0) (J_0)$.

Comment: @PhoemueX I dont follow what you says... Of course $\|\partial\Phi(x_0)-\partial\Phi(x_0+t(x-x_0)\|\to 0$ as $t\to 0$ because $\partial\Phi$ is continuous. But this can be said of any continuous derivative. By the other hand is clear that $\lambda_n(\partial\Phi(x_0)\Bbb R^n)=0$ because $\partial\Phi(x_0)$ is not injective. However I dont see the relation of this things with my question

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but why do you say "$\partial\Phi(x_0)$ is not injective"? Is not that denoting a matrix with values, i.e. the Jacobian matrix evaluated at $x = x_0$ and hence it is non-sense to talk about injective, surjective, etc?

Comment: @manooooh ok, I see what you are asking. The Fréchet derivative at a point of some differentiable function is a linear function, that can be represented by a matrix acting in $\Bbb R^n$ (the Jacobian matrix). In this case we knows that $\partial\Phi(x_0)\notin\mathcal L{\rm aut}(\Bbb R^n)$, that is, it is a linear function in $\Bbb R^n$ that is not an automorphism. This imply that $\partial\Phi(x_0)$ is not surjective, and because it is linear, then it is neither injective. This mean that the Jacobian matrix (that is a square matrix $n\times n$) that represent this function is not invertible.